# Alignment of DIV sections within VS pre-made style

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created an Intranet Website which has a default style that comes with it which is call held in the site.css file. I am trying to have two div sections side by side. In my case I want the Search and Sort div to be on left and data-table div to be on the right. With all of the pre-built styling I am having issues getting it to work. I want both divs to line up but the Search Sort will be skinnier. I have been trying to get it work but have not had any luck and was hoping someone could help get it setup or point me in the right direction.

Here is my view:

```
model  PagedList.IPagedList<ApIssues.Models.AP_Tasks>
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}





     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }

    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Here is the render view 9 with pieces removed to meet post standards:

```
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

        <link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/Content/jHtmlArea/JHtmlArea.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/Content/jHtmlArea/JHtmlArea.Editor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Pacific Power Group</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                       Hello, <span class="username">PACIFICDDA\ajohnson</span>!
                    </section>

                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">




    <div id="task-table" class="issue-table">
        <h2>A/P Issues</h2>
        <p class="filter-table">Search : <input type="search" placeholder="Keyword" name=""></p><table class="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="/apissues?sortOrder=TaskID">Task ID</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="/apissues?sortOrder=TaskDate">Task Date</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="/apissues?sortOrder=InvDate">Invoice Date</a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="/apissues?sortOrder=PO">PO #</a>
                    </th>



                    <td>
                        <a href="/apissues/Edit/25">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/apissues/Task/26">26</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        01/02/2006
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        6046037
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        R
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        TRAMONT
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        AMURPHY
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        SGULLEDGE
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        01/02/2006
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        02/02/2006
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        02/02/2006
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        KENT
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <a href="/apissues/Edit/26">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </tbody></table>
        <div id="Paging" style="text-align:center">
            Page 1
            of 1613

            <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=4">4</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=5">5</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=6">6</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=7">7</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=8">8</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=9">9</a></li><li><a href="/apissues?page=10">10</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-ellipses"><a>…</a></li><li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/apissues?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li><li class="PagedList-skipToLast"><a href="/apissues?page=1613">»»</a></li></ul></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section></div>
    <div id="search" class="search-sort-section">
        <h2>Search and Sort</h2>

<form action="/ApIssues" method="post">            <p>
                <label for="Company:_">Company: </label>
                <select id="company" name="company"><option value=""> </option>
<option>Perkins Pacific</option>
<option>PERKINS POWER NORTHEAST</option>
<option>Pacific Truck Performance</option>
<option>NorthTrends Production</option>
<option>Pacific Detroit Diesel-Allison</option>


<option>Spokane</option>
<option>Springfield</option>
</select>

                <label for="Warehouse:_">Warehouse: </label>
                <select id="warehouse" name="warehouse"><option value=""> </option>
<option>82PK</option>
<option>Anch</option>

<option>Nakn</option>
<option>PGEN</option>
<option>PGRF</option>
<option>PPNE</option>
<option>PPRF</option>
<option>PROD</option>
<option>Psco</option>

<option>Spok</option>
<option>Sprf</option>
</select>

                <label for="Past_Due_Only:_">Past Due Only: </label>
                <select id="pastDue" name="pastDue"><option value=""> </option>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>

                <label for="Assigned_To_By:_">Assigned To/By: </label>
                <select id="assignedToBy" name="assignedToBy"><option value=""> </option>
<option>ABARTON</option>
<option>ABYERS</option>
<option>ACHAVEZ</option>
<option>ADALESANDRO</option>
<option>ADIERKS</option>
<option>ADMINISTRATOR</option>
<option>AKALLENBERGER</option>
<option>ALITTLE</option>
<option>AMACHIN</option>
<option>AOLSON</option>
<option>APATSEL</option>


</select>

            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Open___Completed:_">Open / Completed: </label>
                <select id="openco" name="openco"><option value=""> </option>
<option>Open</option>
<option>Completed</option>
</select>

                <label for="Sort_By:_">Sort By: </label>
                <select id="sortBy" name="sortBy"><option value=""> </option>
<option>Task ID</option>
<option>Warehouse</option>
<option>Assigned To</option>
<option>PO Number</option>
<option>Task Date</option>
</select>

                <label for="PO__:_">PO #: </label>
                <input id="poNumber" name="poNumber" type="text" value="">
                <label for="Freight__:_">Freight #: </label>
                <input id="freightNumber" name="freightNumber" type="text" value="">
                <label for="Vendor_Name:_">Vendor Name: </label>
                <input id="vendorName" name="vendorName" type="text" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Issue_Date">Issue Date</label>
                <input id="beginIssueDate" name="beginIssueDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker"> - <input id="endIssueDate" name="endIssueDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">

                <label for="Invoice_Date">Invoice Date</label>
                <input id="beginInvoiceDate" name="beginInvoiceDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker"> - <input id="endInvoiceDate" name="endInvoiceDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
                <label for="Completed_Date">Completed Date</label>
                <input id="beginCompletedDate" name="beginCompletedDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker"> - <input id="endCompletedDate" name="endCompletedDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">

            </p>
            <p style="float: right">
                <input type="submit" value="Go">
                <input type="button" value="Printable View" onclick="location.href='/ApIssues/PrintablePdf' ">
                <input type="button" value="Add New Task" onclick="location.href='/ApIssues/Create' ">
                <input type="button" value="Reporting" onclick="location.href='/ApIssues/Reporting' ">
            </p>
</form>

    </div>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"8b36f6c8b2764fc79ab3f2d547c4b742"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:49750/7a324d252cb14079b2ebe1fa5ff67dc0/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->





    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/jquery.filtertable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Additional JS/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table').filterTable(
            {
                minRows: 1,
                label: "Search :",
                inputSelector: "#quickFilter",
                placeholder: "Keyword"
            });
        });
        $("#beginIssueDate").datepicker();
        $("#endIssueDate").datepicker();
        $("#beginInvoiceDate").datepicker();
        $("#endInvoiceDate").datepicker();
        $("#beginCompletedDate").datepicker();
        $("#endCompletedDate").datepicker();
    </script><div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>











</body></html>
```

Comment: I am considering just taking out all of the pre-built css

Comment: If you drop your rendered HTML and CSS in a fiddle, it'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where is your css for your issue-table div?

Comment: @Rook It's at the very top of the site.css file.

Comment: Oh.. I see. well. you gotta set the float of issue table to `right`. Also replace the position of your markup; put the issue-table div BEFORE the search-sort-section div. EDIT, I'll put up an answer to better clarify

Comment: @Rook What do you mean by replace the position of my markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML/Razor**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!-- Issue-table before search-sort-section when floating right -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="issue-table">
        <h2>A/P Issues</h2>
        <table class="data-table">
            . . .
        </table>

        <br />
        <div id='Paging' style="text-align:center">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search-sort-section">
        <h2>Search and Sort</h2>
        <!-- Rest of the code -->
        . . .
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.issue-table {
    background: #787878;
    padding: 0px ;
    float: right;
    width:49%;
}

.container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200px;
}

.search-sort-section {
    background: #787878;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    width:45%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your rendered HTML shows that your search-sort-section div is placed OUTSIDE the div with the id of 'Body', this creates your problem as both of your divs aren't in the same container. So I've changed my markup to reflect what the output should be. Put both of the `issue-table` and `search-sort-section` div in the same `container` div. Give the container a width of your choice (100% will be max width of screen) and then adjust the width of your `issue-table` and `search-sort-section` divs accordingly to suit your needs, just make sure they don't overlap each other or they'd be placed one of top of each other.

I also **strongly** suggest that you surround your search criteria within a table like I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpFSL/2/

Comment: So i Just added that to my source and all it did was switch the places of the divs :(

Comment: You mean the issue-table div is not floating to the right?

Comment: the table is floated right but the search is also floated right and below the table

Comment: Can you please show me the rendered html? trying to figure out what exactly is happening

Comment: i added some of the rendered view. I couldnt add the entire thing.

Comment: @user3788671 Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/zpFSL/1/. I've cleared up some of the data from the tables, so know your final product will look different.